# Ionic rebuild custom plugin

Tags: android, maven, gradle, ionic-framework

I need rebuild a custom plugin that i have forked in my private repository.

If i add plugin with: `ionic plugin add ssh:\\private@git\repo.git` the plugin is added in the `package.json` and is download correctly but on: `ionic build android` the plugin is downloaded by maven from some remote location or cache.

I have clean the cache but the plugin isn't rebuilded.

If i compile by `ant release` the plugin and replace the `.jar` file i build correctly the ionic app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the platform each time you update the plugin, it's like this if you edit it in local directory, so maybe it's the same from a distant repo